# Object.keys and Object.values in one function

Tags: javascript

> NOTE: This question is purely out of curiosity.

Is there any builtin javascript function which returns both an object's keys and values?

`{a:1, b:2}.keyValues() ==> [[a,1], [b,2]]`

I don't care if it's ES6 or whatever. I just wanted to know if it was builtin to javascript language at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```

Comment: key difference between `Object.entries` and a `for ... in` loop is ... a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain, while `Object.entries` does not https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries....

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `Object.entries(obj)` function. [mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };
console.log(Object.entries(obj)); // [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 42] ]
```